# Whose body does Lucifer have on Earth, in the FOX TV show?

Tags: lucifer

In the *Lucifer* FOX **TV show**, Lucifer's mother took the body of recently dead humans when she materialized on Earth.  **Whose physical body** does Lucifer have while he is on Earth?

Answer (score 22):

To the best of our knowledge, Lucifer's mother's requirement to take over someone else's body was unique to her. As far as we have seen, the bodies of the angels are their *real physical form*. A few things to note here:

- Lucifer has scars on his back where his wings were removed
- Amenadiel's wings are still attached and unfold from his shoulders
- The angels seem to recognize each other immediately (as when Uriel shows up), while Lucifer didn't think he would recognize his mother on sight.

All of that implies that angels bodies are their own, and thus they always look the same, while Lucifer's mom is incorporeal and needs to hijack a dead body to exist.

This makes sense when you consider the kind of entity that Lucifer/Amenadiel/Uriel/etc are, as opposed to God and Mom. The latter are cosmic entities -- the universe exists because they created it, so it seems self-evident that they have a form that exists "outside" of the world. The angels, on the other hand, were created as part of the world, so they would naturally have form like everything else in the world.

Comment: You may be right, which - BTW - means that if Mom ever goes back to hell, or to heaven, she will leave a corpse for her human family to mourn. However, remember that the sight and possession of Lucifer's wings by an illicit mortal auctioneer caused insanity because they were "celestial."  So, Lucifer (like his wings) is not composed of stuff "of this world" - something to consider.

Comment: @Jessica we can now confirm that this did indeed happen, almost: somehow the body wasn't dead when Mom left it.

Comment: Mum's goddess power probably healed the person that she inhabited and she "possessed" it - like demonic possession.  Supposedly, God possessed the body of a Texas millionaire, who Lucifer met in the mental institution.  God was inside of him not only because of what he said (recognizing Lucifer as his "son"), but because he was able to bring an institute staff member back to life, after she was stabbed to death.

I can hardly wait for the next season, now that (spoiler alert) Lucifer has earned he wings back and no longer has to go up to Heaven with Mum.

Comment: I believe we can also now (maybe) confirm that the angels have the same body on subsequent trips to Earth. If I'm not mistaken, in the episode where Lucifer first shows up in LA (_City of Angels?_), Amenadiel leaves Earth at the end of the episode but he was in the same body as he's in currently. Unless he stayed on Earth (since it didn't actually show him leaving in that episode or arriving on Earth in the pilot), he used the same vessel both times, that's his body.

Answer (score 4):

Updating the answer based on the latest season.

In season 4, it is mentioned that demons can only come to Earth by possessing a body. Similarly, we see Lucifer's mom taking over a body.

Essentially, **all celestial creatures other than angels have no corporeal form**. Therefore, if they wish to exist in our corporeal world, they need to take over a body.

The reason angels do have a corporeal form is because an angel's duty is almost solely defined by their Earthly interventions. Rather than try to hide from sight (Amenadiel could instead freeze time but the other angels have no such skill), they have a humanlike shape which allows them to roam the Earth freely.

On top of that, Lucifer is the one who outlawed demon possession, so it stands to reason that he wouldn't want to possess a body either.

Comment: Demons can only come to Earth _without celestial help_ by possessing a body. I'm pretty sure Maze is not possessing anyone's body, as she cannot go back to Hell on her own -- she needs Lucifer to take her.

Comment: I am fascinated by Maze--she is a 'wild thing' in her own right.  As a demon, she must have assumed a human form by entering a human body (recently deceased), as the others did in Season #4.  However, there seems to be a distinction between inhabiting a living human's body (which I would refer to as 'possession') or a dead body--which is like wearing a costume.  Maybe Lucifer made that distinction for her, or he had not yet imposed his ban on 'possession.'

Comment: Angel bodies: if Lucifer and Amenadiel had human form in Hell or Heaven--even as indestructible immortals--those bodies would be ill-suited to such lethal environments.  Yet, on Earth, they eat and sleep.  There seems to be a contradiction here.  The image of Lucifer in human form ruling over Hell looks incongruous; his demonic form would be more appropriate.  His goddess mother had to eat and sleep on Earth because she had to maintain Charlotte's  human body, in order to inhabit it.   Demons, like Maze, are corpeal beings (unlike deities), and would also have to maintain bodies on Earth.

Comment: @Jessica: `The image of Lucifer in human form ruling over Hell looks incongruous; his demonic form would be more appropriate.` It may be a matter of Lucifer liking his human form. He likes Earth and his non-demonic character/form, and since he's begrudgingly ruling Hell, it's not that farfetched to assume he chooses to retain his human form, even if only to remember who he was on Earth.

Comment: @Jessica Demons seem to be trapped in Hell and they can't leave it in any other way than via possession. Maze, on the other hand,  left Hell together with Lucifer, which would suggest that she is in her own, demonic body (which you can see briefly in one episode - she has a burned half of her face, just like in the original graphic novel)

Answer (score -1):

Maze is different.  Lucifer brought her to Earth with him.  My guess is that demons DO have a physical form in Hell.  Lucifer can probably solidify that form in some way.  The demons in the finale couldn't leave Hell because a Celestial being would have to give them form and bring them up, or, possess dead bodies.  But, in Hell, they all have physical forms.  Just my theory.